# Multiple Images Upload Field in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and i am using [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html) to add a multiple image upload field to a model in my web application. So far i am stuck (I am unable to link the uploaded photos to Hotel model. The Photos get uploaded but are not associated with the hotel model) at how to associate my **Photo Model** to the **Hotels Model** on the HotelCreateView. My question is how do i associate this multiple image filed with my Hotel model so that on creating the hotel the images uploaded are linked to the created hotel. Kindly assist.

Thanks alot

**Hotel Model**

```
class Hotels(models.Model):
    """Stores all the information about the hotel and also used to query hotels"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) #The name of the hotel
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    property_photo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='hotel_photos')
    star_rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,) #Owner of the hotel or person who created the hotel

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'slug')
        verbose_name_plural = 'Hotels'
```

**Photo Model**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_photos')
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'


    def __str__(self):
        """Prints the name of the Photo"""
        return f'{self.hotel} photos'
```

**Forms.py**

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('hotel','file', )
```

**Views.py**

```
class PhotoUploadView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    def get(self, request):
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'hotels/uploads.html', {'photos': photos_list})

    def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, self.request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save(commit=False)
            photo.hotel = self.request.hotel.contact_person
            photo.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: "I am stuck" does not explain what the exact problem is. Are you seeing an error? Is something happening that shouldn't happen? Explain what your code is currently doing and maybe we can then help.

Comment: The code is able to upload the photos but the photos are not associated to the hotel model as i would want them to

Comment: If the photo upload page is for a specific hotel, then it would make sense if the URL for that page contains the id of the hotel, e.g. `/hotels/<id>/photos/upload` that way, you're passing the id of the hotel to the view and can fetch the hotel using the id (you should then check also that the hotel belongs to the current user, just to be sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the widget allowing photos to be uploaded is on the hotel creation page. That is a problem, because this means the hotel is not created yet when photos are being uploaded. So the uploaded photos won't have a `hotel` they can get associated with.

There are two options:

- Move the step to upload the photos to a second step, **after** the hotel has been created. Add the id of hotel that was just created to the url that you call for the `PhotoUploadView` so it's passed as a `kwarg` to the view.

  ```
  # in PhotoUploadView, post()
  if form.is_valid():
      photo = form.save(commit=False)
      try:
          hotel = Hotel.objects.get(
              contact_person=self.request.user.userprofile,  # make sure hotel belongs to user
              id=self.kwargs.get('hotel_id'))
      except Hotel.DoesNotExist:
          raise Http404
      photo.hotel = hotel
      photo.save()
  ```
- Keep track of the uploaded images in the session of the user and associate the uploaded images to the hotel once the `HotelCreationForm` is submitted:

  ```
  # in PhotoUploadView, post()
  if form.is_valid():
      photo = form.save()
      session = self.request.session
      if not session.get('uploaded_photos'):
          session['uploaded_photos'] = [] 
      session['uploaded_photos'].append(photo.id)
      data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}

  # in HotelCreationView, form_valid() or post():
  hotel = form.save()
  session = self.request.session
  if 'uploaded_photos' in session:
      Photo.objects.filter(id__in=session['uploaded_photos']).update(hotel=hotel)
      del session['uploaded_photos']
  ```

  Note that in this case you need to keep `null=True, blank=True` on the `hotel` field in your `Photo` model since you first save the photo without a hotel.

  Also note that if a user never finishes saving the hotel, the photos will still be kept in the db and storage, without hotel associated, so you'll probably want to clean up every now and then (remove all photos that don't have a hotel).

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I went with your first option. But i did a small edit and changed the hotel query to `hotel = Hotels.objects.get(contact_person = self.request.user, id=Hotels.objects.last().id)` as your query was giving me 404 not found error. Right now i am able to attach multiple images and link to a hotel. Thank you very much!

Comment: But using `last()` is a bad idea. You have no guarantee that’s the correct hotel, if multiple users are creating hotels at the same time.

Comment: Oops..i don't know what i was thinking..i will have to have a look at it again

Comment: As I said you have to pass the hotelid somehow. Either in the url of your view or as a hidden field in the form.

Comment: I figured out what i was doing wrong. I was not passing the created hotel id in the URL which is why i was getting 404 error. I have been able to fix it and your code is finally working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much wrong with models but you need to make some changes for `Photo` models

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_photos')
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='photos')
```

Now you should create hotels object first, then when you hit your views for adding images it should set hotel into it by passing hotel id to it or something like that. When in other cases you will be using `hotel` object you can directly access its photos by using `related_name` against it.

There also exist other ways to this problem if you can't create hotels beforehand or something like that but for current scenario this approach will work.

Comment: Sorry this might seems like a silly question. How do i pass the hotel id? How do i get the current hotel id of the hotel that has been created?

Comment: What is your complete use case? Do you create hotels first or not? If yes, and you are using any frontend framework so simply return id on creation of hotel and then while hitting post view of photos just pass that id to create linkage
But you need to mention your exact flow so we can think of the most optimal solution for it

Comment: It's not required to set `related_name`, without it you can access the photos for a `hotel` instance using `hotel.photo_set.all()`. Note also that OP specifically mentioned that he is uploading the photos from the hotel creation page using ajax, so a hotel hasn't been created yet.